# Can I use a Claim variable and pass it into CSOM or PnP calls?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp, .net, core-api

In my asp.net Core webapp, I'm putting the following into Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.Build();
options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

This allows me to get a claim in my Index.cshtml.cs:

```
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity ClaimsId = new();
ClaimsId = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
```

Can I use this claim and pass it into CSOM or PnP calls to SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use PnP Core SDK to connect Asp.net Core to SharePoint Online.

- Below is ConfigureServices method code

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add Microsoft.Identity.Web services
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "User.Read" })
                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            // Add the PnP Core SDK library
            services.AddPnPCore();
            services.Configure<PnPCoreOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("PnPCore"));
            services.AddPnPCoreAuthentication();
            services.Configure<PnPCoreAuthenticationOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("PnPCore"));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

Refer this repository for Sample code in Asp.net core.

- [Source Code](https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/tree/dev/samples/Demo.ASPNetCore)

Refer this docs for detailed step required for configuration

- [PnP Core SDK - ASP.NET Core](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/demos/Demo.ASPNetCore/README.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'll try the sample code to see if it works.

Comment: When I run the sample ASPNetCore sample, I get this error:  Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: 'IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. '

How do I get around this?